# php remove first key of multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to "append" or "push" or "merge" two arrays, with the same structure together.

The Problem is the following:

Array structure:

```
[0] => Array(
    [KEY1] => value
    [KEY2] => value
    [KEY3] => value
 )

[1] => Array(
    [KEY1] => value
    [KEY2] => value
    [KEY3] => value
)
```

If I now add a new array with the exactly SAME structure, (array_push) -> then my Array is looking like this

```
[0] => Array(
     [0] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )

     [1] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )
)
[1] => Array(
     [0] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )

     [1] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )
)
```

How can I merge / combine two or more arrays with a loop so that i get it incremented like this one below? Would be very happy if you could help me.

```
[0] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )

[1] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )
[2] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )

[3] => Array(
                    [KEY1] => value
                    [KEY2] => value
                    [KEY3] => value
                )
```

EDIT:::

My code is the Following

...

```
$myData  = getMyData($myID);

$allData = $myData;

for($i=0; $i < $counter; $i++){                 // Counter works properly
       $otherData = getOtherData($otherID);     // getOtherData has SAME output as getMyData
       array_push($allData, $otherData);
}
```

Comment: Did you try [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array-merge)?

Comment: yes but array_merge does only work on "non asociative" arrays right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i got it now working correctly...

Step 1:
Push the arrays together with [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php)

Step 2: 
Use the PHP function [array_multisort()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-multisort.php)

```
foreach ($termin as $nr => $inhalt)
{
    $band[$nr]  = strtolower( $inhalt['Band'] );
    $ort[$nr]   = strtolower( $inhalt['Ort'] );
    $datum[$nr] = strtolower( $inhalt['Datum'] );
}

array_multisort($datum, SORT_DESC, $termin);
```

The Result was exactly what i needed, sorted by Date.
Thanks for your ideas - this Solution helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to concat the array values from A to another array B as value(even if A[n] is another array) into a sequential index, correct?

I haven't test it but I think this simple approach will work just fine:

```
function concat_array($dest_array, $src_array)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($src_array); $i++)
    {
       if(is_array($src_array[$i]))
          $dest_array = concat_array($dest_array, $src_array[$i]);
        else
           $dest_array [].= $src_array[$i];
    }
    return $dest_array;
}
```

Comment: i am getting with your code the following error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /var/www/vhosts/trendbay.de/httpdocs/chronic.php on line 57
The Idea:
1. Get OWN Data
2. get all positions i need
3. loop through all positions and get data from SQL
4. APPEND DATA INSIDE the loop to the existing array

Comment: @RabidaInternetagentur: This error because the first element in the array is undefiend. Like unset($arr[0]) did happended. I still don't understand what do you mean with "get all positions i need"?